# how to create m-n relationship tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a question about create table. I have two table.
Project table:

```
ID worker1 worker2  department 
 1     1         2    art

staff table:
ID  name
1   tom
2   rose
```

how to nomarlisation the relationship of two table?

Comment: You would describe them as denormalized and a bad database design.  You should have a `ProjectStaff` table, with one row per project and per staff member.

Answer (score 0):

You have to google fisrt. In general relation is made by `JOIN`s.

In your case:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  Project AS P 
  LEFT JOIN Staff AS S1 ON (P.worker1 = S1.ID)
  LEFT JOIN Staff AS S2 ON (P.worker2 = S2.ID)
```

This will show worker1 and worker2 for each project if any.

Go read more about [JOINS](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

It also depend what info exactly do you want to return by the SQL command.

Comment: thanks.however,I want to ask do I need to building a new table to describe this relationship. one worker can attend other projects, so it is m-n relationship

Comment: Then see comment of @Gordon Linoff :). Please edit your question. It sounds unclear.